# How do I find the bundled game that came with my 3DS XL?

Tags: nintendo-3ds-3dsxl-2ds

I recently bought a Nintendo 3DS XL Luigi edition, and [the store page](http://www.mpx.no/nintendo-3ds-xl-luigi-edition/801060#!tab:extra) says it includes The Legend of Zelda: A Link Between Worlds.

However, there is no game cartridge included and the SD card that came along with the device hold no data except for some basics for the system. I've checked the included manuals and there are no codes there. Am I completely missing something here or has the webstore forgot to ship something?

Comment: I forget if it was a code or pre-installed, but I'm pretty sure Zelda was only bundled with the Zelda 3DS, not the Luigi one. Might just be a mis-listing on the store if I had to guess. There was a slip with instructions on now to access the game too I think.

Comment: Even the Amazon page for this edition says it is included. See http://www.amazon.de/Nintendo-3DS-XL-Konsole-Limited/dp/B00FXJREXE (one of the reviewers there mentions it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it says that it comes with the game, and it did not come with the game, you can notify the seller on Amazon, and you should get your game or a code for it.

If they refuse, you can contact Amazon itself and it will rectify the situation.

If it is mis-listed, you should still be able to get your game or a full refund.

Comment: I did contact the original shop and they admitted the fault and shipped the game separately afterwards, so all good.